# Is it possible to find the probability of this event without manually counting the sample space?

Tags: probability

Suppose we are rolling two dies. What would be the probability of the following events?

(a) A = their sum is 7.
(b) B = the first die shows the larger number than the second.
(c) C = both of the dies show the same number.

The sample space for A is $\Omega = \{(1,6),(2,5),(3,4),(4,3),(5,2),(6,1)\}$

So, counting the sample space we find that, $P(A) = \frac {1}{6}$ .

Now, my question is, Is it possible to find the same result by using Permutation or Combination or any other probability formula?

Comment: Well...for A:  there are $36$ equally likely rolls.  Given the value on the first die there is exactly one value the second might have to give the sum $7$.  Hence there are exactly six rolls that give what you want, and $\frac 6{36}=\frac 16$.

Comment: Likewise for (b) for each number on the second die ($d_2$), the first die can take one of $6-d_2$ values, so we need $\tfrac 1{36}\,\sum\limits_{d_2=1}^6(6-d_2)=\tfrac{5+4+3+2+1}{36}=\tfrac{15}{36}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp, lulu's answer is not clear to me.

Comment: @anonymous Whatever is the result of one die, there is only *one* possible result on the other such that their sum is seven. There are *six* equally probable results on that die in total, so the probability of rolling the favoured result is: $\tfrac 1 6$ .

Comment: @GrahamKemp, what did he mean by $\frac {6}{36}$?

Comment: @anonymous There are six possible results of the first die.  All of them can satisfy the favoured space.  $\tfrac 6 {36} = \tfrac 6 6\times \tfrac 1 6$.